# Cannot install helm from MELPA

Tags: package, package-repositories

For some reason, I am unable to install `helm`. My configuration is:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
```

When installing `helm`, I get the message:

```
package-install-from-archive: http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/helm-20181110.1615.tar: Not found
```

I am able to install other packages from MELPA, e.g. `ac-helm`.

Not sure if related, but Emacs asks me to select encoding when doing `(package-refresh-contents)`.

Based on the reply, I tried using `http://melpa.org/packages/` instead with the same result.

Interestingly, the version at `melpa.org/#/` that I see in the browser is 20181112.1139, but the package manager keeps showing the one from two days earlier...

Answer (score 3):

The repo URL got updated quite a while back.  Try using `"http://melpa.org/packages/"` instead of `"http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"`.

Also try to refresh your package list with `M-x package-refresh-contents` then restart.

Comment: Still the same error. Interestingly, the version at `melpa.org/#/` is 20181112.1139, but the package manager keeps showing the one from two days earlier...

Comment: Any change with `package-refresh-contents` or restarting emacs?

Comment: No, nothing. I opened an issue https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/5809, but not sure that I chose the right place.